# Check an extra field in backpack admin login

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I want to check an extra field that is stored in the `users` table (for example `approval` field) in the login process. In what way I can handle this, actually out of the vendor's scope?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [backpackforlaravel: how can we override login controller to integrate 2fa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72380014/backpackforlaravel-how-can-we-override-login-controller-to-integrate-2fa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways that you can solve this problem. Here I will talk about the simplest one:

Step 1: Create a Middleware

```
php artisan make:middleware "MiddlewareName"
```

Step 2: Check your specific column

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if (! auth()->user()->approval) {
        return redirect()->route('route-name');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Step 3: Add your middleware to route (after login)

```
Route::prefix('dashboard')->middleware(['auth', 'auth_user_verified'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', [DashboardController::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard.index');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do that only by creating your custom LoginController and set backpack config to use your controller instead of the vendor's one.

##### Custom Login Controller

```
<?php
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CustomLoginController extends LoginController
{
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        ...

        $credentials = $this->credentials($request);
        $credentials['approved'] = true;

        // Attempt to log the user in
        if ($this->guard()->attempt($credentials)) {
            ...
        }

        // Redirect if login fails
        ...
    }
}
```

now go to **config/backpack/base.php** and declare your custom login controller:

```
...
'setup_auth_routes' => false,
```

##### web.php

```
...
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web', 'prefix' => config('backpack.base.route_prefix')], function () {
    Route::auth();
    Route::get('login', 'Auth\CustomLoginController@login');
});
...
```